# CF 1343A, but two testcases fetch wrong answers

Tags: python, loops

Recently Vova found  candy wrappers. He remembers that he bought  candies during the first day, 2 candies during the second day, 4 candies during the third day, …, 2−1 candies during the -th day. But there is an issue: Vova remembers neither  nor  but he is sure that  and  are positive integers and >1.

Vova will be satisfied if you tell him any positive integer  so there is an integer >1 that +2+4+⋯+2−1=. It is guaranteed that at least one solution exists. Note that >1.

You have to answer  independent test cases.

```
import math
n=int(input())
for i in range(n):
    a=int(input())
    for u in range(int(math.log(a,2))+3,1,-1):
        j=a/((2**u)-1)
        k=a//((2**u)-1)
        if j==k:
            print(j)
            break
```

Since sample cases were very large, I decided to go ahead by taking a logarithmic function of k since the powers of two would rise exponentially thus diminishing the size of the prospective range to be traversed, took an extra 3 just for precaution, which now it seems, upon removal, decreases the number of outputs. I understand the stackoverflow policies on homework and stuff but i think that I have explained my thought process which might make my case better, i think.

Input

```
7
3
6
7
21
28
999999999
999999984
```

Correct Output

```
1
2
1
7
4
333333333
333333328
```

My Output

```
1.0
2.0
1.0
3.0
4.0
333333333.0
32258064.0
```

P.S. I know that the answers are integers but then again that doesn't seem to be the root of my problems, if at all

Comment: What does "CF 1343A" mean?

Comment: I did, Apologies for writing it as cf because other answers starting with "Codeforces" seem to lead to instant bans and stuff

Comment: You're exceeding the limit of floating point precision.

Comment: So, What should I do to uh. make it better?